# How to multi index rows using pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I am new to pandas, whenever I implement my code, first index is repeating for each row.

What I have tried is:

pg, ag, inc are arrays

```
cases=['a1','a2','a3']
data={'RED':rg,'GREEN':gg,'BLUE':bb}
stat_index=['HELO','HERE' ]
df=pd.DataFrame(data,pd.MultiIndex.from_product([cases,stat_index]),['RED','GREEN','BLUE'])
df.to_csv("OUT.CSV")
```

What I get is :

```
             RED         GREEN       BLUE
a1  HELO    304.907     286.074     12.498
a1  HERE    508.670     509.784     94.550
a2  HELO    448.974     509.406     56.466
a2  HERE    764.727     432.084     43.462
a3  HELO    412.539     602.001     10.849
a3  HERE    321.9       603.888     78.847
```

What I actually want is:

```
             RED         GREEN       BLUE
a1  HELO    304.907     286.074     12.498
    HERE    508.670     509.784     94.550
a2  HELO    448.974     509.406     56.466
    HERE    764.727     432.084     43.462
a3  HELO    412.539     602.001     10.849
    HERE    321.9       603.888     78.847
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do it, only if really need it.

It is expected, because if write `MulitIndex` to file is repeated first levels. If display `MultiIndex with DataFrame`, it is not shown by default only. But if change `multi_sparse` to `False` you can check real data:

```
with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df)
             RED    GREEN    BLUE
a1 HELO  304.907  286.074  12.498
a1 HERE  508.670  509.784  94.550
a2 HELO  448.974  509.406  56.466
a2 HERE  764.727  432.084  43.462
a3 HELO  412.539  602.001  10.849
a3 HERE  321.900  603.888  78.847
```

Main reason is compatibility, if use `read_csv` with empty spaces in `MulitIndex`, need preprocessing.

But it is possible:

```
a = df.index.get_level_values(0)
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a.where(a.duplicated(), ''),
                                      df.index.get_level_values(1)])

with pd.option_context('display.multi_sparse', False):
    print (df)
             RED    GREEN    BLUE
   HELO  304.907  286.074  12.498
a1 HERE  508.670  509.784  94.550
   HELO  448.974  509.406  56.466
a2 HERE  764.727  432.084  43.462
   HELO  412.539  602.001  10.849
a3 HERE  321.900  603.888  78.847
```

Comment: I think he wants the output to a csv. Like, the df representation as csv.

Comment: @IMCoins Yes I want to write to csv exaclty as pandas output