# How to transpose row and columns using pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, rows

I am new to pandas, I am getting a result in reverse order of my expected result.

What I have tried is:

o_rg,o_gg,a_rg,a_gg are arrays

```
    df1=pd.DataFrame({'RED':o_rg,'GREEN':o_gg})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'RED':a_rg,'RED':a_gg})
df=df1-(df2)
print(df)
pop_complete = pd.concat([df.T,
                          df1.T,
                          df2.T],
                          keys=["O-A", "O", "A"])
df = pop_complete.swaplevel()
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

print(df)
df.to_csv("OUT.CSV")
```

What I get the output as:

```
             0      1       2
RED        A        14.0    12.0    15.0
           O        14.0    12.0    15.0
           O-A      0.00    0.00    0.00
GREEN      A        12.0    10.0    12.0
           O        14.0    9.0     12.0
           O-A      -2.0    1.0     0.0
```

What I actually want is:

```
                    RED     GREEN       

        A1 O        14.0     14.0
           A        14.0     12.0
           O-A      0.0      2.0

        A3 O        12.0     9.0
           A        12.0     10.0
           O-A      0.0      -1.0

        A8 O        15.0     12.0
           A        15.0     12.0
           O-A      0.0      0.0

 where 'A1','A3','A8' ... can be stored in array cases=[]
```

How to get the actual output?

Comment: I think last edit is really complicated, please create new question.

Comment: @jezrael. Will do it

Comment: @jezrael . Created new. How to get my expected output https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57667106/how-to-get-a-table-in-a-format-using-pandas-and-export-to-csv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simplify your solution with `concat` without transpose and `axis=1`, rename index values and then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
o_rg = [14,12,15]
o_gg = [14,9,12]

a_rg = [14,12,15] 
a_gg = [14,10,15]

df1=pd.DataFrame({'RED':o_rg,'GREEN':o_gg})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'RED':a_rg,'GREEN':a_gg})
df=df1-(df2)
print(df)
   RED  GREEN
0    0      0
1    0     -1
2    0     -3
```

---

```
pop_complete = pd.concat([df, df1, df2], keys=["O-A", "O", "A"], axis=1)
pop_complete.index = ['A1','A3','A8']
print(pop_complete)
   O-A         O         A      
   RED GREEN RED GREEN RED GREEN
A1   0     0  14    14  14    14
A3   0    -1  12     9  12    10
A8   0    -3  15    12  15    15

df1 = pop_complete.stack(0)[['RED','GREEN']].reindex(["O", "A", "O-A"], axis=0, level=1)
print (df1)
        RED  GREEN
A1 O     14     14
   A     14     14
   O-A    0      0
A3 O     12      9
   A     12     10
   O-A    0     -1
A8 O     15     12
   A     15     15
   O-A    0     -3
```

If need create file with no repeating first level of `MultiIndex` (not recommended) use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57570004/2901002).

Comment: Thank you for the code. How can I fetch columns in 'RED' , 'GREEN' order?

Comment: @itsbinz - use `df1 = df1[['RED','GREEN']]`

Comment: How can I name index from a list ,the list may contain [A1,A3,A8],not in series order

Comment: @itsbinz - remove `.rename(lambda x: f'A{x+1}'))` and use `pop_complete.index = [A1,A3,A8]`

Comment: Please refer my expected output

Comment: .Where to add code  pop_complete.index = [A1,A3,A8] ?

Comment: @itsbinz - after `pd.concat([df, df1, df2], 
                          keys=["O-A", "O", "A"], axis=1)` to new row

Comment: index is repeating three time when I export to csv?

Comment: @itsbinz - yes, exactly.

Comment: @ jezrael How can I write only one time for each a1,a3,a8

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198292/discussion-between-jezrael-and-itsbinz).

Comment: Also o data should come first .then a data. How can retrieve data in o ,a o,-a ?. Now it is a,o,o-a order

Comment: @itsbinz - you are right, added `.reindex(["O", "A", "O-A"], axis=0, level=1)` to last row of code.

Comment: Thank you. It works. But when writing to csv, [a1,a3,a8] is repeating.How to avoid that

Comment: @itsbinz - Can you test [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57570004/2901002) ? Last solution in answer.

Comment: @ jezrael Yes I have. It is saying 'IndexError :Too many levels Index has only 1 level,not 2'

Comment: @itsbinz - so `a = df.index.get_level_values(0)
df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([a.where(a.duplicated(), ''),
                                      df.index.get_level_values(1)])` not working? If not, wht is `print (df.index.nlevels)` ?

Comment: @itsbinz - What is `print (df1.index.nlevels)` before write to csv?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198476/discussion-between-itsbinz-and-jezrael).

Comment: .The output is 1

Comment: @itsbinz - There is someting wrong, because if test `df1 = pop_complete.stack(0)[['RED','GREEN']].reindex(["O", "A", "O-A"], axis=0, level=1)` then `print (df1.index.nlevels)` is `2`

Comment: I have updated my requirement as it is not meeting the requirement I wish . How to get the expected now?